# Writing to an eBPF perf buffer event results in SIGBUS error

Tags: ebpf

I have an eBPF program that sends events to user mode via perf_buffer. In user mode I poll for those events. I've noticed that once an event arrives (via callback) I can't seem to write to the memory of that event (results in SIGBUS error).

I've verified in gdb that when trying to write to the memory (using set) I also get a memory error. This leads me to believe that this is by design? I.e., changes to the events transmitted to user mode must be copied if changes are required. I also used gdb to see what the memory regions and associated protections were and the memory region associated with an event from the perf buffer is set to rw-s (which matches what I saw in source for ebpf mmap call).

Any ideas if this is all by design and requires copying before changing?

Comment: Could you share your BPF program with this issue?